# How to maintain collections of data in session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For the purposes of invoicing, I'm keeping track of timesheet entries that are associated with an invoice by storing the selected timesheets in the browser Session and adding/removing entries to that list as the user updates:

The GridView loads all timesheets for the selected company and then indicates by changing row style and select button text:

```
private void HighlightInvoiceTimesheets()
{
    var timesheets = Session["invoiceTimesheets"] as List<Timesheet>;
    var invoiceTotalHours = 0;
    foreach (var timesheet in timesheets)
    {
        var tid = timesheet.Id.ToString();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in ItemsGrid.Rows)
        {
            var btn = row.Cells[ItemsGrid.Columns.Count - 1].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
            if (ItemsGrid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Id"].ToString() == tid)
            {
                row.CssClass = "success";
                btn.Text = "Remove";
                int.TryParse(row.Cells[5].Text, out int timesheetHours);
                invoiceTotalHours += timesheetHours;
            }
        }
    }
    Session["invoiceTotalHours"] = invoiceTotalHours;
    BillableHoursLabel.Text = invoiceTotalHours.ToString();
}
```

When the user "selects" an item in the GridView, it adds or removes the item from the collection in the Session and updates the GridView accordingly:

```
protected void ItemsGrid_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the list of timesheets associated with the invoice.
    var list = (Session["invoiceTimesheets"] == null) ? new List<Timesheet>() : Session["invoiceTimesheets"] as List<Timesheet>;

    // Get the selected timesheet.
    int.TryParse(ItemsGrid.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Values["Id"].ToString(), out int timesheetId);
    var timesheet = timesheetService.GetClearTimesheet(timesheetId);

    // Get the select button to update its text.
    var btn = ItemsGrid.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[ItemsGrid.Columns.Count - 1].Controls[0] as LinkButton;

    // Get the total hours billable for the invoice based on the total hours of the timesheets.
    var invoiceTotalHours = (Session["invoiceTotalHours"] == null) ? 0 : int.Parse(Session["invoiceTotalHours"].ToString());

    if (list.Find(x => x.Id == timesheetId) != null)
    {
        // The list contains the selected item, remove it and indicate removed.
        list.Remove(timesheet);
        ItemsGrid.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].CssClass = "";
        btn.Text = "Select";
        int.TryParse(Session["invoiceTotalHours"].ToString(), out invoiceTotalHours);
        invoiceTotalHours -= timesheet.BillableHours;
    }
    else
    {
        // The list doesn't contain the selected item, add it and indicate added.
        list.Add(timesheet);
        ItemsGrid.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].CssClass = "success";
        btn.Text = "Remove";
        int.TryParse(Session["invoiceTotalHours"].ToString(), out invoiceTotalHours);
        invoiceTotalHours += timesheet.BillableHours;
    }

    BillableHoursLabel.Text = invoiceTotalHours.ToString();
    // Update the collection in the session.
    Session["invoiceTimesheets"] = list;
}
```

This works without any errors but I'm very confused why `list.Remove(timesheet);` doesn't actually update the list in memory.

As a result of this, the collection in the session doesn't get updated and changes made don't reflect on the database.

Comment: You need to update the Session with the modified list.

Comment: That's what the very last line of code there is doing isn't it? `Session["invoiceTimesheets"] = list;`. Either way the problem is that `list`, the variable I'm declaring to work with the items, isn't updating after the `.Remove` call.

Comment: The `Remove` method is looking at reference equality so `timesheet` is not technically in the list. You need to either implement `Equals` such that `Remove` will work how you want or you need to get the actual instance of the timesheet from the list and remove it.

Comment: You're right, I've not seen the last line. Are you sure the `.Remove` is actually removing the element? :)

Comment: Problem seems here `var timesheet = timesheetService.GetClearTimesheet(timesheetId);`, You are not referring the same `list`.

Comment: @Adriani6 can I ask you to actually read the question? I very specifically stated in the question that `list.Remove(timesheet);` ***doesn't*** update the list in memory.

Comment: The confusion here was the wording of your question not that I didn't read it. I thought you're referring to the session itself throughout your question - this was probably caused by your final paragraph. Apologies but rest assured I read your question twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the timesheet you're trying to remove isn't the same object as the one you get from

```
var timesheet = timesheetService.GetClearTimesheet(timesheetId);
```

instead of this:

```
if (list.Find(x => x.Id == timesheetId) != null)
{
    // The list contains the selected item, remove it and indicate removed.
    list.Remove(timesheet);
```

Do this:

```
var timeSheetSession=list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == timesheetId);
if(timeSheetSession!=null)  list.Remove(timeSheetSession);
```

it's pseudo code, i didn't test it.

Comment: Did it for me. Thanks. Now I'm just trying to figure out if EF will update this list per the new selections when I push it to the db or if I'm likely to end up with duplicate records.